# CFSelenium " Failed to start new browser session"

Tags: selenium, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I’m having problems getting going with CFSelenium/TestBox. I’m developing on a Windows 7 VM, Coldfusion 10. I’ve downloaded a fresh copy of cfselenium from https://github.com/teamcfadvance/CFSelenium/archive/master.zip.

My file structure is

```
wwwroot |
  cfselenium |
    Selenium-RC |
        Selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar
    Selenium.cfc
    Server.cfc
  Testbox |
    … various testbox files
   MySite |
    Tests|
        Specs |
            … my test files
            seleniumtest.cfc
        Application.cfc
        Index.cfm
```

MySite/Test/Application.cfc includes mappings for both testbox/ and cfselenium/.

The test suite, seleniumtest.cfc extends testbox.system.BaseSpec, and its beforeAll() and afterAll() functions instantiate selenium, start it, and tear it down:

```
component extends="testbox.system.BaseSpec" {

function beforeAll( ){
        // create Selenium class
        selenium = new cfselenium.Selenium();
        // Start it up.
        selenium.start( "mysite", "*chrome" );
    }

    // executes after all suites+specs in the run() method
    function afterAll(){
        selenium.stop();
        selenium.stopServer();
    }

function run( testResults, testBox ){
    describe('selenium', function(){
        // hello world equivalent
        describe('equality', function(){
            it('true should be true', function(){
                expect( true ).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
}
}
```

New behavior: when passing the following to selenium.start():

```
selenium.start( "https://www.google.com", "*googlechrome" );
```

I get the following error:

> The Response of the Selenium RC is invalid: Failed to start new browser session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.os.WindowsRegistryException: Problem while managing the registry, OS Version '6.1', regVersion1 = false Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03' System info: host: 'myhostname', ip: 'myvm_ip_address', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67' Driver info: driver.version: unknown

For all other url or browser versions I pass to selenium.start() (I've tried '*chrome', '*firefox', '*iexplore', '*iexploreproxy'), I get the following error:

> The Response of the Selenium RC is invalid: Failed to start new browser session: org.openqa.selenium.server.RemoteCommandException: Error while launching browser

From the stack trace, I can see that it fails at selenium.DoCommand().

From another SO post, it was suggested that if port 4444 was currently in use, it could interfere with the selenium-RC server. I restarted my VM and verified that port 4444 was not in use by running

```
Netstat –an | find “4444”
```

After again running the test suite, running netstat with the same command showed

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:4444           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:4444         127.0.0.1:49209        ESTABLISHED
TCP    127.0.0.1:49209        127.0.0.1:4444         ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::]:4444              [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:4444             [::1]:49208            ESTABLISHED
TCP    [::1]:49208            [::1]:4444             ESTABLISHED
```

From looking at cf logs, I see the following:

> Apr 29, 2016 09:44:23 AM Information [ajp-bio-8012-exec-3] - Starting HTTP request {URL='http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/', method='POST'}

Is there supposed to be a selenium-server folder under wwwroot? Is that the webdriver?

EDIT: Per Dan's answer, I've downloaded chromedriver_win32 from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/, extracted to C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver, added that to my PATH, and rebooted the VM. After changing the driver from '*googlechrome' to '*chrome', it seems to work... I was able to run the following test successfully:

```
function testIncludes(){
      selenium.open("https://www.google.com");
      $assert.isEqual("Google", selenium.getTitle());
 }
```

So I think we're on our way here.

Seem to have IE driver working as well.

Comment: James - there is a syntax error:  super.beforeAll(‘siteUnderTest', '*selectedBrowser);   needs another single quote after *selectedBrowser   ... maybe a cut and paste error?

Comment: @MarkAKruger - yes, fixed.

Comment: Perhaps another typo here but the first single quote of the super call is not a _normal_ single quote - `super.beforeAll(‘siteUnderTest',`. And where did you get `cfselenium.BaseSpec` that you are extending from the cfc? I don't see that as part of the project on GitHub.

Comment: @Miguel-F - I think I might have edited part of the post in Word prior to posting which would explain the odd quote. Fixed. As far as cfselenium.BaseSpec, you are correct; doesn't exist in that repository; I literally have no idea where I got it from now; I've added its contents to the post.

Comment: @Miguel-F - I've also just tried replacing the contents of wwwroot/cfselenium with a new copy from the repo, and have changed seleniumtest.cfc to extend testbox.system.BaseSpec instead, and to use the beforeAll/AfterAll code from cfselenium.BaseSpec as well. Still get the same error.

Comment: I would suggest going back to the original repo that is posted on GitHub. Go through their documented usage and test cases. See if you can get that working first. Assuming that works, you can start adding the other modules (BaseSpec) and see if that works or fails. That should tell you where things are going wrong at least. Then we can go from there.

Comment: @Miguel-F - as per my previous comment, I've dl'ed a fresh copy from the repo, replaced the existing contents of wwwroot/cfselenium, and have modified the test suite so that it no longer extends cfselenium.BaseSpec. Same error. It tries to start selenium but dies at selenium.DoCommand(). I've updated the post.

Comment: @Miguel-F - Just discovered new error when trying to start with browser='*googlechrome'. Posted above. Stack trace on request.

Comment: Have you looked in the Windows event logs to see if any errors/details are being reported there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110655/discussion-between-earachefl-and-miguel-f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium can't launch Chrome without Chrome Driver (as Chrome is no longer part of webkit) and Selenium can only launch webkit browsers by default. You should be able to launch Firefox (if it's installed) without needing any additional binaries.

To get Chrome working you will need to do the following:

1. Download the chrome driver bin.
2. Add it to your path.
3. Selenium should be able to launch the browser.

There may be some other issues in the code, but I feel like the comments have provided enough feedback in that regard.

You can download the driver from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

**UPDATED**

IE requires a driver as well:

> The Internet Explorer Driver Server
>   This is required if you want to make use of the latest and greatest features of the WebDriver InternetExplorerDriver. Please make sure that this is available on your $PATH (or %PATH% on Windows) in order for the IE Driver to work as expected.
>
> Download version 2.53.0 for (recommended) [32 Bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.53.0.zip%2032%20bit%20Windows%20IE) or [64 bit Windows IE](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.53/IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0.zip)

The above was from: http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ in regards to driving windows. It seems that the host with the browser needs to run a Selenium Web Driver specifically for IE

Firefox also publishes their own driver:

> Firefox driver is included in the selenium-server-stanalone.jar available in the downloads. The driver comes in the form of an xpi (firefox extension) which is added to the firefox profile when you start a new instance of FirefoxDriver.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver). It operates similar to the Chrome and IE drivers. The important thing to realize is that because the tests are run in the on one host and browsers are remote to where the tests are executed from you may want to look at Selenium Grid as well.

Comment: out of luck with IE? We're required to support it. Will try with Chrome. Forgot that I had uninstalled Firefox on my VM.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect that this seems to be working, after changing the driver parameter to '*chrome'. Thanks Dan!

Comment: Super! I'll take a look at IE stuff and update my answer. If Chrome works then all the network bits are worked out.

Comment: Actually I think I've got it working with IE as well. downloaded the 32 bit version from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/, added it the existing driver folder, and using '*iexplore' got success. Part of my problem is that I'm new to the selenium universe and was trying to figure things out from the cfselenium documentation, not the selenium docs.

Comment: I updated my answer to include some more info. I'd also mention that https://saucelabs.com will run remote instances for you. I've used it in the past to immense success. The other option may be to run a SeleniumGrid (which is what SauceLabs is) on your own. That will just give you a farm of browsers to use that all operate the same way. It should allow you to mentally split the browsers from the tests and make debugging easier.